# Threads hanging permanently on JDBC Teradata requests

Tags: java, jdbc, teradata

I'm using JDBC to query a Teradata server. There are up to 100 simultaneous requests, each one using a fresh connection, and closing it at the end. After some hours of work, some of the threads performing the requests get stuck indefinitely. Eventually a system restart is needed.
From inspecting the call stacks, I see that the threads are in a socket read state, and that it happens when **preparing a statement** or when **closing the connection**:

Case 1:

```
java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
               at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
               at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:129)
               at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.io.TDNetworkIOIF.read(TDNetworkIOIF.java:649)
               at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.io.TDPacketStream.readStream(TDPacketStream.java:818)
               at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.statemachine.StatementReceiveState.action(StatementReceiveState.java:125)
               at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.statemachine.StatementController.runBody(StatementController.java:112)
               at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.statemachine.StatementController.run(StatementController.java:103)
               at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.Statement.executeStatement(Statement.java:340)
               at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.Statement.prepareRequest(Statement.java:507)
               - locked <0x00002aab4f787518> (a com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.PreparedStatement)
               at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.PreparedStatement.<init>(PreparedStatement.java:66)
               at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.TDSession.createPreparedStatement(TDSession.java:723)
               at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_3.ifjdbc_4.TeraLocalPreparedStatement.<init>(TeraLocalPreparedStatement.java:89)
               at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_3.ifjdbc_4.TeraLocalConnection.prepareStatement(TeraLocalConnection.java:333)
               at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_3.ifjdbc_4.TeraLocalConnection.prepareStatement(TeraLocalConnection.java:152)
...
```

Case 2:

```
java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
               at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
               at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:129)
               at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.io.TDNetworkIOIF.read(TDNetworkIOIF.java:649)
               at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.io.TDPacketStream.readStream(TDPacketStream.java:818)
               at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.io.TDPacketStream.readStream(TDPacketStream.java:794)
               at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc.GenericLogOffRspState.action(GenericLogOffRspState.java:66)
               at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc.GenericLogoffController.run(GenericLogoffController.java:43)
               - locked <..> (a com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.io.TDNetworkIOIF)
               at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.TDSession.close(TDSession.java:476)
               at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_3.ifjdbc_4.TeraLocalConnection.close(TeraLocalConnection.java:259)
...
```

I'm using the JDBC Teradata driver version 13.10.00.10.

Any idea why it happens?
This issue is very painful for us and any help will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried upgrading to the latest patch release of the JDBC driver? 13.10.00.18 was released 2011-04-12. Release 13.10.00.15 included a patch to correct a problem with multi-threaded concurrent logon attempts throwing a GSSException: Error during MIC calculation.

If this doesn't remedy the problem and your client/company is a Teradata customer I would suggest that opening an incident with the Teradata Global Support Center.

Comment: Thanks, i just wrote a simple piece of code to reproduce it, and I will probably open an incident later.